# How to download source code with Pacman on Arch Linux?

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I am using [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux). I want to do the same thing like `apt-get source coreutils`; is it possible to download sources with [Pacman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacman_%28package_manager%29)? I didn't find a solution in the [man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

How can I get the source code of a package?

Comment: You can also get individual packages via svn: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Getting_PKGBUILDS_From_SVN

Answer (score 24, accepted):

---

**2018 Update:**

The `abs` tool described below has been [deprecated](https://www.archlinux.org/news/deprecation-of-abs/) and it along with its rsync endpoint have been dropped since mid 2017.

The `asp` tool now provides similar functionality. More information [here](https://github.com/falconindy/asp/blob/master/man/asp.1.txt).

---

As already mentioned you can use the ABS (Arch Build System):

Install it using pacman:

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel abs
```

First, download the ABS tree:

```
sudo abs
```

Then, get a specific package:

```
sudo abs [package_name]
```

Then copy the package, whose source you want to have, from the local abs tree (e.g. `/var/abs/core/findutils`) to another directory, e.g. `/home/blabla/abs`

Then run `makepkg`:

- if you only want to get the sources and don't want to build the package you can run `makepkg -od`
- otherwise run `makepkg -s`, which will then handle all the package's dependencies automatically
- watch out becaouse makepkg will overwrite your modifications, use `makepkg -e` to build your local sources instead

If you want to install the package you've built, run

```
pacman -U name-of-package.xz
```

Comment: `makepkg -i` will install the package as well; it's also possible to use `makepkg -ei` to compile whatever is in src and install the ensuing package in one take

Answer (score 48):

1. `pacman -S asp`
2. say if you want the source code of the Linux command `find`

   1. find out which package the command `find` belongs to:
      `pacman -Qo  $(which find)`.  The result is
      "/usr/bin/find is owned by findutils 4.4.2-3".
3. `asp export findutils`
4. ```
   cd findutils
   makepkg -o
   ```

Now you have your source code.

Comment: If you just want one package, you can do something like `abs core/wpa_supplicant`, where you prepend the package repository. You can also use `ABSROOT=/tmp/ abs core/wpa_supplicant` if you don't want to use `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on not being sudo to download a package (which is possible with apt-get source). By the way in step 5.1 if you are looking for `find` just type `pacman -Qo find`. I personnally prefer to use `pkgfile find`. Just try it.

Comment: You could use `makepkg -o` to only download and patch the source, instead of building the while package!

Comment: FYI, In my case, I tried to downalod `python` source, but I got `Missing dependencies` when `makepkg -o`. Use `makepkg -o -i` to skip dependency checking.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: This answer is outdated due to changes on ABS.**

You get the package sources from the Arch Linux SVN repository, called ABS.

First find the package online:
http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=coreutils

Then, on the package details page, on the right side use the SVN links, e.g.:
http://repos.archlinux.org/wsvn/packages/coreutils/trunk/

And there, you have a sweet "Download" button, in this case it leads to:
http://repos.archlinux.org/wsvn/packages/coreutils/trunk/?op=dl&isdir=1

It is a little bit more complicated than `apt-get source`. But perhaps you find a tool on AUR that does the job for you, for example yaourt supports building from sources and exporting them.

Comment: I just forgot to mention that the mentioned ABS also comes with user-space tools, so you can in fact automatically checkout all packages etc. However it is overkill for single packages.

Comment: The repo site is just blank now.

Comment: Right, but the links on the package details page are still there, and the packages can be now found here: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/

Comment: I can't see a single `Download` link, though. The only way I can see is to download each file individually by clicking on the `plain` link.

Comment: That's because they changed to git. You can use the git command line tool though to download the whole tree at once.

Comment: As already explained here and in https://www.archlinux.org/news/deprecation-of-abs/ **abs** has been replaced in favor of the new utitlity **asp**
To download the sources of a specific package, you might try the following (it worked for me one second ago, but I can't confirm it always will):
sudo pacman -S asp;
asp checkout nano;
cd repos/core-x86_64/;
makepkg;h